# Automatically running a function inside an object when that object is called

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I am building a text based choice RPG game using Javascript. I am able to add functions inside of an object and run them, however, I want the function to run if the option ( text node ) is chosen.

Currently, I declare a function, and then call it at the bottom of the page. The issue is, I want to function to run as soon as the choice is chosen.

Here is the code I have so far...

```js
function addRadiatedStatus(){
    character.radiated = true;
}

const textNodes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Do you want to help this person?",
        options: [
           {
            text: "Yes",
            nextText: 2
           },
           {
            text: "No",
            nextText: 2
           },
        ],
        faction: "Greaser"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "It was a trap, do you run or kill them?",
        options: [
           {
            text: "Run",
            nextText: 3,
            damage: 0,
           },
           {
            text: "Kill",
            nextText: 5,
            damage: 8,
            moneyDrop: 20,
            radiationDamage: 2,
            function: function update(){
            if(character.greaser == true && textNodes[1].faction == 
            "greaser"){
                console.log("greaser check worked");
            }
                console.log("upadte function worked")
            character.health -= this.damage;
            character.cash += this.moneyDrop;
            character.radiationLevel += this.radiationDamage;
            character.maxHP -= this.radiationDamage;
            if(this.radiationDamage >= 1 ){
                addRadiatedStatus();
            }
            console.log("character HP" + " " +  character.health);
            console.log("character maxHP" + " " +  character.maxHP);
            console.log("moneyDrop " + " " +  this.moneyDrop);
            console.log("character cash" + " " +  character.cash);
            console.log("radiation level" + " " +  character.radiationLevel);
            console.log("character Raditated?" + " " +  character.radiated);

            }
           }
        ],
        faction: "Greaser",
    }
]

textNodes[1].options[1].function();
```

I tried a few different things, including adding another key `run: update()` , `run: this.update()`, `run: this.function`, etc.

I am also a little confused because I thought that ES6 allows me to remove the `function` keyword, but that doesn't seem to be allowed ( I am probably just doing it wrong, or running into an issue based on how I set up my object ).

I am not sure how to go from calling `textNodes[1].options[1].function` to dynamically calling whichever function is nested within a specific choice option.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this section to this:

```
update: (function(){
        console.log("upadte function worked")
        character.health -= this.damage;
        character.cash += this.moneyDrop;
        character.radiationLevel += this.radiationDamage;
        character.maxHP -= this.radiationDamage;
        if(this.radiationDamage >= 1 ){
            addRadiatedStatus();
        }
        console.log("character HP" + " " +  character.health);
        console.log("character maxHP" + " " +  character.maxHP);
        console.log("moneyDrop " + " " +  this.moneyDrop);
        console.log("character cash" + " " +  character.cash);
        console.log("radiation level" + " " +  character.radiationLevel);
        console.log("character Raditated?" + " " +  character.radiated);
    });
```

The `function` keyword has been changed to `update`, then the function has been changed to an anonymous function ... You should refrain from using js keywords for your user-defined ones.
Then the anonymous function will not execute until you call it:

```
textNodes[1].options[1].update()
```

---

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:
This shows that you have to actually access the function and any other key for that matter for you to access the values.

```js
var text = [
    {
          data1: "here",
       data2: (function(){
          return "You have to explicitly call me!"
   })
    }
]
console.log("Without calling any data:   " + text[0])
console.log("When you call data2:   " + text[0].data2())
console.log("Let us access data1:   " + text[0].data1)
```

Comment: I think you either misunderstood or I explained incorrectly.

I want to refrain from using `textNodes[1]...` all together, because I do not want to call the function unless that choice is chosen in my game AND I do not want to have to add the index of each call textNode and option.

Comment: I added an edit to my function. I added an if/else to check if the NPC faction of the question is the same as the players faction. This kinda leads me to a similar issue with calling the function automatically, that is trying to avoid manually adding indexs.

Comment: It's taken me a few minutes to understand exactly what you're talking about, but I think I've gotten it -- But I'll stick with my `update` instead of your `function` keyword. **You want the function inside `update` to be called instantly without having to access it**. As far as I know, that's not possible because the function is a `key` inside the `options` object ... the function is not in a position to run until it is called, and that is only done by manually accessing it -- (This is just like defining a normal function - **which you have to explicitly call for it to run**)

Comment: View the snippet in the edited answer above that explains what I mean